# How can I disable banshee screams in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I play a ton of Mass Effect 3 multiplayer and I can't take the banshee noises anymore.  How can I disable them, and if possible, only do it for multiplayer mode?  I've tried just deleting the .afc/.pfc files but it doesn't work.

I'd love it even more if I could replace the sounds with something else, like I could just replace the sound files with another renamed sound file, but at this point I'll just settle for getting rid of them.

Comment: heh that wall to wall platinum mode noise